# How to stop a number from sending replies

Tags: twilio

There is a number that has been automatically replying with SMS, and of course each reply costs money. It was not a number that was ever sent a message to, so it is baffling as why it is sending automatic responses back.

How does one block a number so not to receive messages from?

Update : Made it clear that reply was in SMS format.

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment yet but please see [this](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/is-there-a-way-to-block-incoming-sms-on-my-twilio-phone-number)

> Unlike voice, there’s no way to block specific SMS messages or sending
>   parties